# Spring Security Authentication using DynamoDB

Tags: spring-security, amazon-dynamodb

Does anyone know how to provide spring security authentication using `DynamoDB`? In other words, how would you convert/represent the following `configAuthentication` method using `DynamoDB`?

```
@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from appuser where username = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, rolename from appuser natural join user_role natural join role where username = ?;");
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-security-spring-data-dynamodb is the closest I've found to an official answer, but it hasn't been updated in three years, so I'm skeptical of that package.  You're already using https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb which is currently maintained, but I don't see anything there about JWT / Spring Security.

Answer (score 3):

You can use anything as a Spring Security authentication backend. You would need to write custom query logic in a class that implements the `UserDetailsService` interface and return a domain object that implements the `UserDetails` interface, but you can use that class.

Your configuration would like something like

```
  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(myCustomDynamoDbDetailService);
}
```

Where `myCustomDynamoDBDetailService` is your class that implements `UserDetailService` and does the lookup by username from DynamoDB.